# Kubernetes Ingress - Pass only sub path to backend and not full path

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-application-gateway

I want a Ingress, that routes **host.com/abc/xyz** to  **service/xyz**.
I have the following configuration but its routing  **host.com/abc/xyz** to  **service/abc/xyz**.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-draining: "true"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-draining-timeout: "30"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-timeout: "300"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-status-codes: "200-399, 401"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
  generation: 1
  name: serviceAingress
  namespace: pantry-services
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.net
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: serviceA
          servicePort: 8083
        path: /abc/*
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          serviceName: serviceA
          servicePort: 8083
        path: /abc
        pathType: Prefix
```

How can I route myhost.net/abc/* to service/* ? the abc should not be included in the backend call. I've tried pathType as ImplementationSpecific too

Comment: Similar thinkg is described in Azure Application Gateway Ingress docs on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/annotations.md#backend-path-prefix). This may help you finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the backend-path-prefix annotation as described here - https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/annotations.md#backend-path-prefix

Answer (score -1):

If your **service** is a host name. Name-based virtual hosts support routing HTTP traffic to multiple host names at the same IP address.
Would Suggest you to please use the below. yaml code

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name-virtual-host-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.net
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "abc/*"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: service
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/*"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 80
```

If you create an Ingress resource without any hosts defined in the rules, then any web traffic to the IP address of your Ingress controller can be matched without a name based virtual host being required.

For example, the following Ingress routes traffic requested for myhost.net/abc/ to service1, service/* to service2

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/